# Attribute tables spanning multiple pages in QGIS / page breaks?

Tags: qgis, printing, atlas

I am trying to make a city guide using QGIS atlas function which contains indexes to find certain streets / POIs quickly.

Using [QGIS expression to access page-number of atlas for certain features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362615/qgis-expression-to-access-page-number-of-atlas-for-certain-features/362622#362622) I already managed to create such a attribute table. However, there are more features than fit on one page.

How can I make page-breaks in a attribute table?

I know I can set the maximum number of displayed records, but not the start offset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you don't have an additional page yet, add one: Menu <kbd>Layout</kbd> > <kbd>Add Pages</kbd>. Continue on this next, empty page.

1. Add an attribute table to your layout. Place, style and size it the way that it fits the page.
2. In item properties, expand <kbd>Frames</kbd> entry and for <kbd>Resize Mode</kbd>, select <kbd>Repeat until Finished</kbd>.
3. Go to <kbd>Feature Filtering</kbd> entry and for Maximum rows set the number of features (lines) you have - or a number above it.

QGIS will add as many pages with the same size/position of the attribute table so that every feature will be represented - in the example in the screenshot with 3333 features, I get in total 79 pages: the first page with the map + 78 pages for the attribute table.

[image]

Comment: what if something like a textfield is on page 1 below the table - is it possible to have this textfield then always below the table, no matter how many pages the table is spanning?

Comment: Yes, this should repeat, but check it out